# Matrix element replacement Octave

Tags: matrix, octave

I've a matrix
        `A = [0.125680   0.543107   0.40088]`

If a number in that matrix is greater or equal .5 I want to replace it with 1.

If a number is less than .5 I want to replace it with 0.

So my final matrix will be `B = [0 1 0]`. How will I do that without `for` loop?

Answer (score 1):

Get it. It simple.

`B = A >= .5;`